# DataGridView.Refresh() Not working

Tags: vb.net, winforms

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        If e.ColumnIndex <> 3 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim i, j, k As Integer
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index
        j = DataGridView1.Item(0, i).Value
        k = DataGridView1.Item(2, i).Value

        Dim con As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Chuttu VB\Projects\LIC\LIC.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True")
        Dim sql As New SqlCommand("SELECT PaidStatus FROM PremiumDate WHERE PolicyNumber=" & j & "AND PremiumNumber=" & k, con)
        Dim sqlPaid As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE PremiumDate SET PaidStatus='Paid' WHERE PolicyNumber=" & j & "AND PremiumNumber=" & k, con)
        Dim sqlUnPaid As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("UPDATE PremiumDate SET PaidStatus='Un-Paid' WHERE PolicyNumber=" & j & "AND PremiumNumber=" & k, con)
        Try
            con.Open()

            If sql.ExecuteScalar = "Un-Paid" Then
                sqlPaid.ExecuteNonQuery()
                sqlPaid.Dispose()
            ElseIf sql.ExecuteScalar = "Paid" Then
                sqlUnPaid.ExecuteNonQuery()
                sqlUnPaid.Dispose()

            End If
            con.Close()
            con.Dispose()

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
        DataGridView1.Refresh()



    End Sub
```

I am using the `CellClick` event to update DB column `PaidStatus` from `Paid` to `Un-Paid` and vice-versa....Once updated i want the updated  data to be reflected..i am using `DataGridView1.Refresh()`....but it does not show the updated data from the DB..i have to close the application and re launch it to see the changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating result into database so you need to rebind the DataGridView.

```
'Fetch result from the database and populate the new data source.
DataGridView1.DataSource=your_data_source
```